# How to hold the expression when using ToExpression with TeXForm

Tags: expression-manipulation, hold

I know

```
{1, 1} // Apply[Defer@*Plus]
```

can return

> 1+1

But if I want hold the form from TeXForm,what should I do?

```
ToExpression["1+1", TeXForm]
```

will return 2 . But I don't know how to *Defer* the [`Plus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html).

Comment: How about `1+1//HoldForm//TeXForm`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the 3rd argument of [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html).

```
ToExpression["1+1", TeXForm, Hold]
```

If the TeX string is coming from untrusted sources,  it is better to use [`HoldComplete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldComplete.html) for complete safety. Try this: `ToExpression["\\text{Evaluate}(\\text{Print}(gotcha))", TeXForm, Defer]`.

Every function that extracts an expression that might evaluate has some facilities to keep the result held.

- [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) has a similar 3rd argument
- [`LinkRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinkRead.html) has a similar 2nd argument
- [`Read`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Read.html) has `Read[file, Hold[Expression]]`
- etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
ToExpression["\\frac{1}{\\sqrt{5}}+\\frac{1}{\\sqrt{5}}",TeXForm,Hold]
```

will return

```
(* Hold[1/Sqrt[5] + 1/Sqrt[5]] *)
```

which I assume is what you need?

Comment: 16 second difference :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way:(from QQ: 2716697201)

```
ToExpression["1+1", TeXForm] // Trace // #[[2]] &
```

whose FullForm is

> HoldForm[Plus[1,1]]

Comment: You really should not do this though.

Comment: I agree. That's pretty inventive, but it's a dark, dark art.